# KeyError: in user defined function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below function to print duplicate values exist in dataframe.

```
def duplicateCrosscheck(dataDF, columnList):
     print('Duplicate checking', columnList)
     dataDup = dataDF[dataDF.duplicated([columnList], keep=False)]
     print(dataDup.values)
     return
```

I will pass data Frame name and list of columns to check duplicates.

```
duplicateCrosscheck(dataT, "'Country', 'Indicator', 'variable'")
```

But getting below error: 
KeyError: "'Country', 'Indicator', 'variable'"

If I execute below script it works fine.

```
dataT[dataT.duplicated(['Country', 'Indicator', 'variable'], keep=False)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in **one** string, containing quotes and commas. Python won't interpret that as 3 separate strings, no. Those quotes and commas don't have any special meaning, they are just more data inside a string.

Alter your function to pass `columnList` on directly:

```
def duplicateCrosscheck(dataDF, columnList):
     print('Duplicate checking', columnList)
     dataDup = dataDF[dataDF.duplicated(columnList, keep=False)]
     print(dataDup.values)
     return
```

and pass in an actual list:

```
duplicateCrosscheck(dataT, ['Country', 'Indicator', 'variable'])
```